# Distinguish \nameref references in print version

Tags: hyperref, formatting, links

I used the `\nameref` command to reference to names of captions etc.
I also used the option `colorlinks=true` so I have colored references which can be distinguished form "normal" text.

In my print version of the document I colored the links to black.
Now I'd like to set them to *italic* or surround them with apostrophes or something like that.

I already tried to renew the `\nameref` command, but I didn't get it to work

```
\renewcommand{\nameref}{\emph{\nameref{#1}}}
```

I allways get an error message, which says

> LaTeX Error: `\namref` undefined.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: If it is exactly that message then you have a typo. The redefinition can't work this way, though. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48575/5049 for reasons why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option `hidelinks` is available since `hyperref` 2011/02/05 v6.82a.
`\nameref` can be redefined the following way (assuming the star form is not needed):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}[2011/02/05]

\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifdefinable{\myorg@nameref}{%
    \LetLtxMacro\myorg@nameref\nameref
    \DeclareRobustCommand*{\nameref}[1]{%
      \emph{\myorg@nameref{#1}}%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Hello World}
\label{sec:hello}
This is section \nameref{sec:hello}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Would you consider something like `\LetLtxMacro*\newcs\oldcs` that checks whether `\newcs` is already defined?

Comment: @egreg You can already use `\LetLtxMacro\newcs\oldcs` if `\oldcs` is undefined. Then `\newcs` is just undefined (as `\let` would have done). An error/warning message does not help much, if then `\newcs` is defined with `\oldcs`. Therefore I have used `\@ifdefinable` to get an error message _and_ to disable the redefinition.

Comment: The error would be raised anyway, and such redefinitions by a user (as opposed to a package writer) are usually made during document preparation, so it's not so important that the compilation is "almost successful". In any case the code must be corrected.

Answer (score 4):

Starting of what you wrote, I've made this :

```
\newcommand{\Newnameref}[1]{\textit{\nameref{#1}}}
```

The `[1]` says that this command will only take one input, and the `#1` is what you'll write bewteen braces in yous source file.

You'll use it like this :

```
\Newnameref{sec:section1}
```

It works for me ;)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer