# Overriding commands

Tags: document-classes

How can I partially re-implement an existing command in Latex?

I have a `\documentclass` with:

```
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[My sample class]
\LoadClass{article}
```

When someone uses `\subsection{}`, I really want to treat it as if they wrote `\subsection*{}` (no section numbers). In my `*.cls` I've tried:

```
\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{\subsection*}
```

But this just causes an infinite loop in Latex and I need to kill the process.
I've also tried:

```
\let\subsection\subsection*
```

But this simply lets `\subsection` equal itself and then prints a `*`

Comment: what about just `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}`?

Comment: sorry, for subsection it's 1.

Comment: There is no need to redefined macros here, as touhami mentions, just globally disable the section numbering for subsections and below. Setting `secnumdepth` to `1` tells LaTeX to number down to _and including_ `section`, but not `subsection` and below

Comment: In case you're interested, this explains why your macro doesn't work and Steven's does: [Redefine marginpar with \renewcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48575/172164) (it's basically the same question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LaTeX has a built-in mechanism for this. Each sectioning command is assigned a level

> part −1
>   chapter 0
>   section 1
>   subsection 2
>   subsubsection 3
>   paragraph 4
>   subparagraph 5

A class might not have chapters, but for uniformity the levels are always the same.

You can decide up to what level sectional titles are numbered by setting the counter `secnumdepth`:

```latex
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
```

will only number parts, chapters (if provided by the class) and sections.

There is a companion counter, `tocdepth`, that controls what sectioning levels are listed in the table of contents.

Of course, users can override your setting, if they know about `secnumdepth`. You can't do much about that.

Even if you decide to go the “redefine” way with

```latex
\let\latex@subsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\latex@subsection*}
```

a user can still do

```latex
\makeatletter
\let\subsection\latex@subsection
\makeatother
```

and override your decision.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\svsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand\subsection[1]{\svsubsection*{#1}}
\begin{document}
\section{Section Name}
\subsection{Subsection Name}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just had to re-implement `\includegraphics` to include a default `[max width=\textwidth]` and this worked perfectly!